# Read the paths from the text file

Tags: python, arrays, os.walk

I wrote a script which will scan the shared folders and get the file age of all the files in those folders and some other file meta info.

```
my_paths = []
for p in ['\\\\data\\hold\\app1','\\\\data\\hold\\app2']:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(p):
        my_paths.append(filenames)
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
                string_output='Age :' +age_file(full_path)+'\n'+'File Size : '+file_size(full_path)+'\n'
                print(string_output)
                #create(string_output);
```

I have to hard code all the shares in the code, instead I thought of making the script to read from a text file where I can update all the paths.

```
text.txt

\\data\hold\app1
\\data\hold\app2
```

revamp code,

```
my_paths = []
for line in open(r'd:\mydata\text.txt').readlines():
    my_paths.append(line.strip())
    print  my_paths
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(line):
        my_paths.append(filenames)
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            if last_modified(full_path) < threshold:
                string_output='Age :' +age_file(full_path)+'\n'+'File Size : '+file_size(full_path)+'\n'
                print(string_output)
                #create(string_output);
```

my_paths returning the data like ['\\data\hold\app1','\\data\hold\app2'] but somehow the rest is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to strip the line you read in the loop:

```
...
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(line.strip()):
...
```

Comment: I already strip at top, so tried assigning a variable to my_paths.append and called. But it is also not working

Comment: When you call `.strip()`, it doesn't change the variable in place but rather returns another (stripped) copy. So you would need to call it in the `os.walk()` call too. Other than that, the iteration on `os.walk()` works for me. Maybe, try to be more precise about how it "doesn't work"?